# array a objects (diccionario) en un formulario react.js

Tags: array, reactjs, web, formularios, diccionarios

tengo un codigo de un forulario que la api es metodo PUT, tengo una parte en donde tengo que enviar en forma de objects, pero al memonto de enviarlo me lo envia como un array, tambien me dicen que tengo que enviarlos si es true o false  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    const {
      state,
      city,
      mild_symptoms = [],
       } = event

    const YES = "Si"
      console.log(event)

    try {
      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      const url =
        "XXXXXXXXX";
      myHeaders.append(
        "x-api-key",
        "XXXXX"
      );

      myHeaders.append("state", state);
      myHeaders.append("city", city);
      myHeaders.append(
        "mild_symptoms",
        `{"flu_syndrome": ${mild_symptoms.includes("flu_syndrome")}, "conjunctivitis": ${mild_symptoms.includes("conjunctivitis")}, "muscle_pain": ${mild_symptoms.includes("muscle_pain")}}`
      );
      var requestOptions = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: "cors"
      };
      const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
      console.log("FIRST RESPONSE ", response);
      const result = await response.text();
      console.log("RESULT", result);
      Modal.success({
        title: "Éxito",
        content: "Datos enviados correctamente",
        onOk: ()=>{
          window.location.href = "https://covid19.gob.sv/orientaciones-tecnicas/"
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERROR", error);
    }
```

este lo tengo que enviar como un objects y no como array

```
"mild_symptoms",
        `{"flu_syndrome": ${mild_symptoms.includes("flu_syndrome")}, "conjunctivitis": ${mild_symptoms.includes("conjunctivitis")}, "muscle_pain": ${mild_symptoms.includes("muscle_pain")}}`
      );
```

aqui esta el ejemplo que me pasaron en postman [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que seria por objeto, esto es lo que me paso mi jefe https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos

Comment: Al parecer y segun lo que indicas lo que deseas es aplicar POO.`Programacion Orientada a Objetos`, deberias de leerte un poco de POO en javascript. aunque al final dicho objeto se parseará en JSON para poder ser enviado por Header.

Answer (score 0):

Quiza el backend que recibe ese JSON, esta en python, por eso te especifica que se envie como diccionario.
Diccionario seria como un objeto en javascript, asi q lo q tienes que hacer, es convertir tu Array a un objeto. El problema es que tu array no tiene un formato para convertirlo a diccionario, en todo caso, tienes que pedirle al backend, que te diga en que formato quiere que se lo envies.

Comment: me dijeron que no, que lo debia pasar a objects y la verdad es que no se como